# Replace SMB address to go to file/folder location on Mac

Tags: macos, path, applescript, mounted-volumes

I'm on MacOS and I'm regularly sent file paths in the format of "smb://196.168.1.13/filepath/filename". I need change it to a more friendly "/Volumes/filepath/filename".

I've been searching through here for an AppleScript solution but I can't find a one that I can get to work.

Complete noob so please be gentle.

[edit] I think I cracked it. The script checks mounts the volume if necessary, converts the file path to a more friendly MacOS one then opens the file/folder location.[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked it. Takes the smb address (mounts the volume if needed) and opens the location of the file/folder.

This is specific to our server. Change the address to your setup.

```
on run
    --get the clipboard info
    set Storage to get the clipboard

    --Mount the volume if required
    if Storage contains "smb://192.168.1.13/" then
        set findString to "smb://192.168.1.13"
        set theVolume to "/Volumes/"
        set mountedVolumes to every paragraph of (do shell script "mount | awk -F' on ' '{print $2}' | awk -F' \\\\(' '{print $1}'")
        if theVolume is in mountedVolumes then
            --Volume is mounted
        else
            mount volume "smb://192.168.1.13/WIP"
        end if
    end if
    
    --Convert path to mac friendly path
    set replacementString to "/Volumes"
    set newPath to do shell script "sed 's|" & quoted form of findString & "|" & quoted form of replacementString & "|g' <<< " & quoted form of Storage
    
    --Open the file/folder location
    set myFolderLocation to newPath
    tell application "Finder"
        reveal POSIX file myFolderLocation as text
    end tell
end run
```